# UTF-8 Turkish Character on header

Tags: alfresco

I'm using alfresco 5.2. I have got o problem. Turkish characters look like ? in the footer of the index page.
There is a UTF-8 problem in this section. how can i solve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Did you customise the footer yourself?

Comment: Yes, I'm customised.

Comment: I've tried native2ascii but it wasn't.

Comment: What character encoding did you save your file using?

Comment: I'm encoded it with native2ascii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to enable UTF-8 in your tomcat configurations. In [TOMCAT_HOME]/conf/server.xml you can add URIEncoding="UTF-8" to your Connector port such as

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="32768"/>
```